# Google Tag Manger Server container not seeing any response in preview tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I setup my own custom server. I can't see any repose in my preview page. see the screenshot
[image]

I setup two server. 1) Manually provision a preview server 2) server-side tagging cluster

my nginx configuration:

```
 location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        }
```

I also get `ok` response  for https://my_subdomain/healthz

I am not understanding why I am not seeing any request in my server preview page.